# Configure Cisco 2801 that has NAT overload to allow access to WAN from LAN

Tags: cisco

I have a server behind my Cisco (IOS, not ASA) that is running NAT overload (PAT?) with port forwarding for specific services (http/https) to a statically IP'ed server that is on the same subnet as my normal internal LAN. How can I configure the router to allow my local users to access the public interface so that they can get to the web server. (Split DNS is not an option for me at this time)

Details:
Router Public IP: 1.2.3.4/30 (DHCP Assigned)
Router Private LAN IP : 10.10.10.1/24
Server behind firewall IP: 10.10.10.25/24

What I am trying to do is allow my internal LAN to access a website that is locally hosted:

www.example.com 1.2.3.4

When I try to access www.example.com from behind the router, it fails, since the router will not allow the traffic to pass out and then back in.

Let me know if there are any further details that you need

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

Adding a DNS zone on your local DNS server for example.com (which you said isn't an option).

Hairpin NAT aka NAT-on-a-stick. https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12102421/nat-hairpinning